# Livecharts Scatter Plot: Set custom numbers for axis labels

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Is there a way to customize which numbers will appear as axis labels on a scatter plot in livecharts?

For example: If a data set ranges from 1-10, instead of the axis labels showing 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ; is there a way to set them as, let's say, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8 (in the appropriate places of course)?

Comment: Show the code you tried and explain how the outcome differed from what you expected.